# How to get an array from json?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How would I do the following in BigQuery:

```
SELECT CAST(JSON '[1, 2]' AS ARRAY<INTEGER>)
```

> Invalid cast from JSON to ARRAY at [1:13]

JSON is so much more difficult to work with than the normal types in BQ!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it can help :

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY ('[1, 2]') AS your_array
```

In this case, the result is an array as expected

Comment: thanks, what's the difference between this and the `JSON_VALUE_ARRAY` function?

Comment: oh this one returns `JSON` type and the other returns a native array, and `null` if it's not a single typed array, such as `SELECT JSON_VALUE_ARRAY ('[[null, null]]') AS your_array,
JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY ('[[null, null]]') AS your_array`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE_ARRAY('[1,2]') AS sample_array;
```

As mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value_array), this **json function** extracts the json value. For more json functions you can access the link provided above.

**Output**:

[image]